# Prevent running sub routines twice for improve performance?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, performance, file-search

I have a winform that does file searching and display results in a datagridview. I also have picture boxes that display the file as well. The process: enter file name and click search, displays results in grid and pictures in picture box.

I want to be able to click search again but this time if it is the same file, i don't want to run my picture process therefore resulting in better performance. Not sure on how to achieve this?

Comment: How can we tell you how to fix/optimize your code when there is no code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Static variable and set/check it each time the method is called:

```
Public Sub SearchForFile(filename As String)
    Static lastFile As String = Nothing
    Try
        'don't run again if the same file is searched for
        If lastFile = filename Then Return

        'do your file searching here
    Finally
        'always set the last filename to the one we just searched for
        lastFile = filename
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: it gets hung up after searching again for the same file, doesn't end the end try loop.

Comment: There is no loop in the code I posted, so I'm guessing you don't have a `return` somewhere in your code?

Comment: What do you mean by hung up? It can only hang in a loop, so can't hang on a simple line of code.

Comment: could i set lastFile to nothing on textbox change event therefore if i search again the same file name lastFile would still run the picture process again?

Comment: Yes but you would have to declare it at the class level rather than the method level

Comment: public lastFile as string = nothing ?

Comment: That should work. You might want to declare it `Shared` as well